# In BigQuery, what is the workaround for _TABLE_SUFFIX to pull the correct schema?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, schema

When using StandardSQL with _TABLE_SUFFIX, BigQuery interprets the schema based on the last table saved into the dataset. The result is that if there are more than one kind of table in the dataset, the following query will return NULL values for an incorrect schema:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM `dataset.*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '%some_table_name'
```

So if I save a table named `dataset.different_table` and then execute the above query, then the result won't be as expected.

Is there a workaround for this workflow? An alternative to using _TABLE_SUFFIX?